# How do I keep my webpage font from being stretched by recommended display settings?

Tags: html, css, width

Newer laptops seem to come with a recommended display font-size of 150% but they aren't seeing my webpage properly as items are larger and stretched.

How can I get them to see the webpage properly despite their default display settings of 150%?

Comment: You should use "em" instead percent if you want a scalable font-size.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, you should try using rem or em for your font sizes, so that they aren't directly tied to the size of the screen. It might make sense to use media queries to appropriately adjust the font size, which bootstrap does a [good job of covering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/typography/#responsive-typography), however the code given there is SASS, not CSS. The approach caries over, but you'd have to use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) directly.

With regards to sizing everything besides fonts, it is almost always a good idea to leverage the max and min attributes if you are using percents. For example, a class like

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

would allow the element to fit the full width of its parent, but stop at 600px.
This prevents the element from being stretched too far on displays with different resolutions and zooms. For more info, check out the rest of [W3Schools's Responsive Web Design guide](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp), where you learn how css libraries like bootstrap are implemented.